# Java selenium load javascript table

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am using Java selenium to extract data from a URL where it uploads dynamic data using javascript.
I have written code to do my job and it works fine. The main problem here is that the URL page sometimes takes too much time to upload data and occasionally causes no result or an error. My idea is to show the result if it is present, otherwise display in the user query that the result was not loaded.

Here is my part of code:

```
WebDriver drivermasspro = new FirefoxDriver();
drivermasspro.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
drivermasspro.get("http://example.com/xyz_proxi.jsp#{\"searched_button\":\"proteins\",\"peptide\":\""+userpepseq+"\"}");
String sCellValuemasspro = drivermasspro.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@class='result']/tbody")).getText();
drivermasspro.quit();
```

where the user can give input from command line , in this case, I am testing with this input:

```
VALVYGQMNEPPGAR
```

Due to loading time I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException:  Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 60.11 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'pallabs-air.proteincentre.com', ip: '172.16.1.118', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0.1, platform=MAC, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,    takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 435c3ba8-24b8-164e-8c4f-e5415dd79b22
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:179)
at extract.data.ExtractDataDynamic.main(ExtractDataDynamic.java:71)
```

I have seen that people have asked this question many times but that doesn't give my answer. How can I wait until javascript dynamic table uploads and if data exists then print and otherwise show none.
One more question I have, how can I extract data without opening firefox browser?
Anyone there to help me?
Thanks

Comment: The fact that it's timing out after 60 seconds suggests that you actually have a real problem. Are you perhaps somehow blocking the browser JS thread?

Comment: I have tried to use this one also but same error occasionally:drivermassid.manage().window().maximize();. After driver quit, I  am just trying to read data. So I think I am not blocking that until firefox gets close.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem. At least it is working perfectly for me but anyone wants to add more efficient solution you are always welcome.

```
WebDriver drivermasspro = new FirefoxDriver();
drivermasspro.get("http://exmaple.com/xyz_proxi.jsp#{\"searched_button\":\"proteins\",\"peptide\":\""+userpepseq+"\"}");
Thread.sleep(5000);
String sCellValuemasspro = drivermasspro.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@class='result']/tbody")).getText();
drivermasspro.close();
```